# Offchain workers in parachain

Tags: parachain, offchain

On a parachain (Substrate polkadot-v0.9.20 branch), I am trying to trigger some offchain tasks using an offchain worker in my pallet, but the task is not triggered. I checked that the `on_finalize` hook is correctly triggered, but not the `offchain_worker`...
I also tried the `--offchain-worker always` command line flag, without any success.

Is this supposed to work on parachain nodes ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Did you initialise the offchain worker in service.rs file? These lines have to  be added to initialise offchain worker https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/150c6c9e66bd4e866cfd4704d4d2a16799edc2c0/node/src/service.rs#L205

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it has to work too. As suggested in the previous answer check that you are doing the initialisation.

Do the Substrate tutorial: [Add offchain workers](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-application-logic/add-offchain-workers/) to see how to implement the pallet in the runtime

Or see this previous StackExchange answer with an example: [Working up-to-date complete source code for offchain workers?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/5617/2762)

Another guide that is a bit old, but worth to check is this: [Transactions in Off-chain Workers](https://github.com/JoshOrndorff/recipes/blob/master/text/off-chain-workers/transactions.md)