# Working up-to-date complete source code for offchain workers?

Tags: offchain-worker, offchain

Hello Substrate community

I've been trying to integrate an offchain worker capable of API calls on top of an existing Substrate cluster of 3 nodes I already have up and running successfully (based on [Substrate Node Template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/commit/278e2438f5c3f1167dea8d2c4c7b4d570045140c))

I already:

1. Went through https://docs.substrate.io/reference/how-to-guides/offchain-workers/
2. Tried to integrate [the Paritytech official offchain exemple pallet](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/polkadot-v0.9.29/frame/examples/offchain-worker) (reference from 1.)
3. Tried to run [this end-to-end demo](https://github.com/jimmychu0807/substrate-offchain-worker-demo) (also a reference from 1.)
4. Tried to integrate [this exemple](https://gnunicorn.github.io/substrate-offchain-cb/) (also a reference from 1.)

But there's always a problem:

- Either the code is few years old (point 4)
- Or at least one year old and based on Substrate node template v3 instead of v4 (point 3, and it doesn't even start anyway..)
- The reference pallet from Parity (point 2) is just the pallet, without the code for the runtime, so a lot of dependencies are broken...

[image]

Would anyone here able to share a working end-to-end exemple (runtime + pallet) based on node-template v4, or be able to guide me on how to successfully update the runtime for the pallet in point 3 to start working?

Any help is appreciated :)

Lucas

Comment: "an offchain worker capable of API calls on top of an existing" What do you mean exactly by API calls? `pallet-election-provider-multi-phase` is a pallet that uses offchain workers and is compatible with substrate master, and it does submit transactions back to the chain.

Comment: https://github.com/MrishoLukamba/substrate-tutorials/tree/mhl-OCW-solution/exercises/ex05-offchain-workers

Comment: Thanks a lot @MrishoLukamba, I will take a look, I hope the runtime has all necessary dependencies to make that pallet works, or that the tutorial gives some clues on how to add these dependencies, thanks again

Comment: @kianenigma , I meant "calling an external service, outside of Substrate, through a HTTP GET or HTTP PUT call, from the off-chain worker";  it looks like the pallet you suggested is very thoroughly documented according to what I've found at https://crates.parity.io/src/pallet_election_provider_multi_phase/lib.rs.html, I will definitely sit down and go deeper in it as well, thank you!

Comment: Follow the How-to guides from the Substrate page: https://docs.substrate.io/reference/how-to-guides/offchain-workers/offchain-transactions/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/mns23/substrate-node-template/tree/offchain-worker-example) I integrated the official example [offchain-worker](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/frame/examples/offchain-worker) pallet into a v0.9.28 Substrate node template.
Check last commit to see the integration through runtime/src/lib.rs, node/src/service.rs and Cargo files.

Comment: Thanks a lot, just tried and it compiles! Makes it an easy base to start from.